# Retrieve mean time between failure within given date range parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below is what i have tried,

```
select machine_id, count(incident_id) "No_Incident", 
(fail_date BETWEEN (24 * to_date('&From_date_', 'DDMMYYYY') AND to_date('&To_Date','DDMMYYYY') / count(incident_id))) "MTBF"
from mytable;
```

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  A non-working query is _not_ helpful.  Also, tag a single database -- the one you are really using.

Comment: SYNTAX!!!! `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE....`

Comment: Removed the conflicting tags! Are you using MySQL or Oracle??

Comment: using oracle PLSQL

Comment: please edit question and add details there

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu thank you for the resposne.kindly refer to the updated 'expected result' information.

Comment: @RiggsFolly please refer to the updated information.any help much appreciated.

Comment: @isuru_thilina, firstly we need sample data to understand what you are up to. we need data type of your table as well. then you need to include expected output but not by providing screenshot. You need to learn community standards. please respect the people who tries to help everyone.

Comment: please share your table schema or columns in table

Comment: @ggordon thank you

machine_id varchar2(4000)
incident_no varchar2(100)
Fail_date   Date

Comment: @isuru_thilina thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
SELECT  machine_id, count(incident_id) "No_Incident",
        MAX(ROUND((ABS((TO_DATE('01-02-2019','DD-MM-YYYY') -
       TO_DATE('03-02-2019'||' 23:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))*24))))
       /count(incident_id) AS MTBF
FROM
mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following examples:

since `machine_id` is not being aggregated (eg. being counted), I have used the group by to provide the Mean Time Between failure (MTBF) for each machine. If you would like for all machines, simple remove `machine_id` from the SELECT clause and the GROUP BY `machine_id`

You had a syntax error with your query as you were querying the range of dates using the `between` in your select clause. NB. I have modified this and placed it in a where clause. Based on how you execute your query (eq sql clients), how you may handle parameters may differ.

#### Using Oracle

```
SELECT 
    machine_id,
    count(incident_id) as "No_Incidents",
    (
      EXTRACT( 
         HOUR FROM 
         CAST(MAX(fail_date) AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(MIN(fail_date) AS TIMESTAMP)
      ) +
      EXTRACT( 
         DAY FROM 
         CAST(MAX(fail_date) AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(MIN(fail_date) AS TIMESTAMP)
      ) * 24
    )/count(incident_id) as "MTBF"
FROM
   mytable
WHERE
   fail_date BETWEEN to_date('&From_date_', 'DDMMYYYY') AND to_date('&To_Date','DDMMYYYY')
GROUP BY
   machine_id
```

In the oracle example, I converted the dates using [CAST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) to a TIMESTAMP before finding the difference (date_max - date_min gives a date interval ). Extracting (using [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm)) and summing the hours (hours and days*24) gives the total hours.

#### Using MySQL

```
SELECT 
    machine_id,
    count(incident_id) as "No_Incidents",
    (
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,min(fail_date),max(fail_date))
    )/count(incident_id) as "MTBF"
FROM
   mytable
WHERE
   fail_date BETWEEN to_date('&From_date_', 'DDMMYYYY') AND to_date('&To_Date','DDMMYYYY')
GROUP BY
   machine_id
```

I have also used the [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)  in MYSQL function to determine the difference between the dates in hours.

Comment: thank you.. i am getting invalid identifier error for the timestampdiff. am using oracle 12c. any idea?

Comment: @isuru_thilina Please mark this answer as complete for others in the stackoverflow community to reference for similar problems if it helped.